# Draw in non-normalised coordinates - glFrustum

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d, openframeworks

On using glFrustum,

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 0.1, 1000.0);
glLoadMatrxi(GL_MODELVIEW);
glBegin(GL_QUADS); //A room's left wall
glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -0.4);
glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -0.4);
glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
```

All my drawings happen in -1, 1 (notice the above snippet for //A room's left wall) i.e.
 X- axis: -1 becomes the left, 1 becomes the right with origin in centre.
Y-Axis: 1 becomes the top and -1 becomes the right with origin in the center

Does glFrustum automatically change my coordinates to [-1,1]?

Normally, I would draw a cube with by specifying the screen coordinates as follows:
eg: `ofBox(512,384,0,10)` gives me a box in the center of screen [Window width: 1024, Window Height: 768]

What if I want to keep drawing as I draw normally in my pixel coordinates and don't want to make things complex for myself by trying to convert from pixel coordinates drawing to normalised coordinates even if I use `glFrustum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're still having a hard time imagining what a frustum is, and how it relates to the projection. Simply spoken a frustum is a pyramid with its tip cut off at some distance:

[image: frustum]

If used as a OpenGL projection matrix the bounds of the frustum define a volume in *view space coordinates* (i.e. after the modelview transformation) that will be turned into a cube of extents {-1, 1}²×{0, 1} by the projection transformation and homogenous divide.

The extents of the near plane define the extents in view space coordinates – that is world space with the view point being placed at (0,0,0) – that will be mapped (i.e. "stretched" and/or "pinched") to the extents of the rendering window defined with `glViewport`.

In short words: You use `glViewport` to define the pixel coordinates in the window where things should go and `glFrustum` to sort of "cut" a slice out of view space (which is world space moved in such a way that the camera is at (0,0,0)).

Comment: After the perspective divide, the x- and y-dimensions of your cube are mapped to [-1,1].  The depth coordinate range, however, is [0,1].

Comment: @radical7: This is indeed the case, however OP is struggling with the concept of the view space frustum. I didn't want to overcomplicate the NDC side of the process.

Comment: @datenwolf : Isn't `glFrustum` a step of projective transformation which comes after the Viewing and Modelling Transformations in the timeline? The object space coordinates are converted to Eye Space- > Clip Space -> NDC Space. Then why are these arugments in View/Eye Space as you mentioned?

Comment: @user1240679: glFrustum is no step at all, but a helper function to calculate and set the projection matrix. And by *definition* the parameters of glFrustum used for calculation of the volume in eye space. BTW, due to your questions I have begun writing a illustration program to demonstrate how a frustum and a projection relate. It's not completed yet, but you can have a look at it already at https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum